# function in a module that uses variable from main module

Tags: python, import, module

I think this is not duplicated, however if it is, let me know.

I just want to be able to use a Function inside another module but, inside that function from the other module, a variable from Main is imported. This gives me circular error.

i have tried:

```
#MAIN.py
from function import test
numero = 1
test()
```

```
#function.py
from main import numero
def test():
  print(numero)
```

This is a just an example of the problem I face in:

https://replit.com/@FelixCaba/CALCULADORA-LOL#main.py

Comment: What about creating another module for storing constants? Or getting these constants from an external source, e.g. text, json file?

Comment: cant you just pass numero as a parameter to the test function, the will allow you to decouple these?

Comment: Moreover, pay attention that you are not actually calling the `test` function, you must write `test()`.

Comment: @blunova the problem is that I just wrote this as an example, I have a much bigger program but the problem is the same, and it doesnt use constants.

Comment: So more details from your side are needed IMHO. Maybe the way you are designing your program could be improved.

Comment: @blunova I added a link to the program itself, i can make all inside one module with ease, but for some purposes I want some functions to be inside a module, its cleaner.

Comment: better define it as `def test(numero):` and execute as `test(numero)`. This makes code cleaner and more readable. Using external variable can make only problem to debug code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix to this problem is assigning the variables inside the Function Module, I would prefer not to, but I guess its some easy Fix.

```
def Suma():
    numero1 = float(input("Introduce el numero 1 de la suma "))
    numero2 = float(input("Introduce el numero 2 de la suma "))
    resultado = numero1 + numero2 
    print(resultado)
```

Instead of assigning numero 1 & 2 inside main module.